# Integrating an API into Python to create a Twitter BOT

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I'm relatively new to Python and coding in general and I'm having trouble using an API in a small Twitter BOT program

The API I'm trying to use is from opensea.io
API Docs: https://docs.opensea.io/reference

I have managed to pull the data from the API but don't know the correct way to get it to print (or send Tweet with) certain data

```
import tweepy
import time
import requests

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("*************","******************")

auth.set_access_token("*******************","*****************")

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

url = "https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/events"

querystring = {"collection_slug":"sandbox","event_type":"created","only_opensea":"false","offset":"0","limit":"1"}

response = requests.request("GET", url, params=querystring)
link = response.link

print(link)
time.sleep(60)

# api.update_status(status = response)
```

Comment: What does your code print? I believe `response.content` should have useful data. Are you sure everything up until the request itself is OK? Sometimes API settings are trickier than they seem.

Comment: I don't see an actual question here... You presented some code and didn't say what is wrong with it. What is the problem? Are you getting an error? Wrong output? What is your expected output?

Comment: i'm looking for the command/method that will isolate the link/URL from the returned data so that the BOT can then be instructed to tweet the link/URL (just not sure of the correct terminology)

Answer (score 1):

This method returns the raw bytes of the data payload

```
response.content()
```

This method returns a string representation of the data payload

```
response.text()
```

This method is convenient when the API returns JSON

```
response.json()
```

For a detailed tutorial [refer this](https://realpython.com/python-requests/)

For a short overview [refer this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_response.asp)

**Tip:**
Always check the **[status code](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/?highlight=OK#status-code-lookup)** of the response before using `response.json()`

if the result was written in JSON format and the status code is not [**OK**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.html) then it raises an **error**

How to get the response's status code?

```py
response.status_code
```

Check the status for success response:

```py
if resp.OK :
   do something
```

There is a property called ok in the Response object that returns True if the status code is 2xx or 3xx but not a 4xx or a 5xx.

or

```py
if 200 <= response.status_code <= 299:
    do something
```

1xx — This lets us know that the request was received

2xx — This shows that the request was successful

3xx — This is for redirects (temporary and permanent)

4xx — Client errors

5xx — Server errors

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'm looking for the command/method that will isolate the link/URL from the returned data so that the BOT can then be instructed to tweet the link/URL (just not sure of the correct terminology)